# Enter password only once for ssh

Tags: ssh, command-line-interface, linux

I use the following commands to sync folders. Each command requires me to type in the password. How can I group these commands to only enter the password once? Thanks.

rsync -ave ssh /opt/lampp/htdocs/new/folder1/ root@111.111.111.111:/home/folder1/

rsync -ave ssh /opt/lampp/htdocs/new/folder2/ root@111.111.111.111:/home/folder2/

rsync -ave ssh /opt/lampp/htdocs/new/folder3/ root@111.111.111.111:/home/folder3/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Setup key-based authentication, and use an ssh-agent.

Comment: Can someone expand on this for the beginners? Definitely not for me, Just for the beginners...

Comment: Probably could but I believe key-based authentication is well covered by numerous other questions on serverfault, and tons of articles on Google.

Answer (score 2):

On a bash prompt:

```
rsync -ave ssh /opt/lampp/htdocs/new/folder{1,2,3} root@111.111.111.111:/home/
```

If you do folder{1,2,3}/ the wrong thing will happen..

This is the same command in a more verbose version:

```
 rsync -ave ssh /opt/lampp/htdocs/new/folder1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/new/folder2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/new/folder3 root@111.111.111.111:/home/
```

**Using Authorized_keys**

You can also add command specific public keys, add this to authorized_keys:

command="rsync --server -vldogDtpr --partial . /home/",no-pty,no-agent-forwarding,no-port-forwarding ssh-rsa AA[...]3RIy/FbGhV5Xg1jILhhgb[...]iTqYKj/FgF0+vZJaQ== erik@myhost

Problem is I don't know how to limit rsync to just allowing transfering to folder1,2,3..

Answer (score 1):

http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

This link should assist you.